# Update cart item number instead of appending new item

Tags: react-native, redux, cart

If an already added product is again added to the cart then only cart number should increase but the function appends the data to the list and the product gets duplicate in the cart view. How to make sure check if the product already exists then only increment or decrement the count.
below is the code to update product

```
const initialState = {
    cart: [],
    total: 0,
}


const cartItems = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: [action.payload, ...state.cart],
                total: state.total + 1
            }
            // return [...state,action.payload]
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART' :
            return state.filter(cartItems => cartItems.id !== action.payload.id)
    }
    return state
}
```

A single item from the data will be like

```
{key:'1', type:"EARRINGS", pic:require('../../assets/earring.jpg'),price:"200"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the same key for the items you can do like below

```
     case 'ADD_TO_CART':
       {
           const updatedCart = [...state.cart];
           const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
           if(item)
           {
            item.count++;
           }
           else{
             updatedCart.push(action.payload);
           }
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updatedCart,
                total: state.total + 1
            }
       }
```

The logic would search for items in the array and increase the count or add a new item to the array.

Comment: This works perfectly however when I apply the same ADD_TO_CART case to a plus icon to increase the count, it appends the new array in the original array and everything messes up. How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sending the same object as the payload? Or is it different?

Comment: I think I am sending the wrong payload bcoz I send the whole cart array instead of a single item. please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996065/unable-to-delete-or-increase-cart-count?noredirect=1#comment111400818_62996065

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

```
case UPDATE_CART:
            let receivedItem = action.payload
            let itemList = state.cart
            let stepToUpdate = itemList.findIndex(el => el.id === receivedItem.id);
            itemList[stepToUpdate] = { ... itemList[stepToUpdate], key: receivedItem };
            return { ...state, cart: itemList }
```

'id' is a unique thing to update specific item present in your cart. It cab be product id or some other id.

```
itemList.findIndex(el => el.id === receivedItem.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of achieving this. You can create actions to INCREMENT/DECREMENT in case you know the product is added (eg: on the cart summary).

And you can also let this behaviour inside the ADD_TO_CART action if you don't know whether the product is added or not:

```
case "ADD_TO_CART": {
   const isProductAdded = state.cart.find(
     item => action.payload.id === item.id
   );
   return {
     ...state,
     cart: isProductAdded
       ? state.cart.map(item => {
           if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
             item.qty++;
           }
           return item;
         })
       : [action.payload, ...state.cart],
     total: state.total + 1
   };
}
```