# Unable to delete or increase cart count

Tags: react-native, redux, cart

On a cart page, there are two icons plus and minus to increase and decrease the count respectively. when I use to increase the count, it appends a new array into the array instead of an object. The increase code is

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART':
       {
           const updatedCart = [...state.cart];
           const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
           if(item)
           {
            item.count++;
           }
           else{
             updatedCart.push(action.payload);
           }
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updatedCart,
                total: state.total + 1
            }
       }
```

For decrease, the code is

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART' :
            let updatedCart = [...state.cart];
            const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
            if (item && action.payload.count > 0)
            {
                action.payload.count--
            } else {
               updatedCart = state.cart.filter(i => i.key !== action.payload.key) 
            }
            return {...state, cart: updatedCart, total : state.total - 1 }
```

**Map Dispatch to props code**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
    removeItem:(cart) =>dispatch({type:'REMOVE_FROM_CART',payload:cart}),
    addItemsToCart:(cart) =>dispatch({type:'ADD_TO_CART',payload:cart})
  }
}
```

**onPress Function calling**

```
<AntDesign name="pluscircleo" size={30} color="black" onPress={() =>this.props.removeItem(this.props.cartItems.cart)}
```

Comment: Nothing  seemed wrong with code. did you try to debug your code ? is there any action dispatched on adding/removing anything?

Comment: actually addtocart case works perfectly from the product screen but when i move to cart screen where all added products are displayed, here a plus icon is used to increase the quantity count. the icon uses the same addtocart function but instead of increasing quantity, it adds a new product in the cart with no data. And remove function doesnt work, I think logic is wrong

Comment: yes, if something like that is happening then you may calling a wrong function on clicking + button

Comment: onPress={() =>this.props.removeItem(this.props.cartItems.cart) is the problem, here you should have an object like {key:1,count:2} something not the whole cart

Comment: i tried it with ```this.props.cartItems.cart.key``` but did'nt worked

Comment: @LovepreetSingh Assuming the plus icon button is in an item screen, do you have access to the item key of that specific item ?

Comment: The plus icon is in the cart screen and yes I can get the specific key of the first item by this.props.cartItems.cart[0].key. How to identify which product key needs to be passed

Comment: Resolved it bro, the increment and the decrement both. Now in decrement, the value is going in minus, will find a way to fix this. Thanks for your support and guidance

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan hey bro, could you please help me with this. I am unable to make a fetch req. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032784/stripe-payment-network-request-failed/