# Stripe Payment - Network request failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, stripe-payments, fetch-api

I am using stripe for the payment in react native app. For the backend, I have NodeJS running and it is working fine means when I pass the token, the payment gets successfully debited. However, in react native side, I am getting customer card details and creating token and then passing this token to my NodeJS server for payment but every time it gets network error.

***React native Code***

```
pay() {
        stripe.createToken({
            card: {
                "number": '4242424242424242',
                "exp_month": 12,
                "exp_year": 2020,
                "cvc": '123',
                "name": "RAM",
               
            }
            }).then((token_object) => {
                
                fetch('https://<IP address>:3000/pay', {
                    method:"POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify(token_object)
                }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                  console.log('Success:', data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.error('Error:', error.message);
                });
            console.log(token_object.id);
            });
    }
```

***NODEJS code***

```
const express = require ('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const stripe = require ('stripe')('sk_test_')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.send("hello from NodeJS!!!!")
})

app.post('/pay',async (req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        const {token} = req.body,
         charge = await stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 15 * 100,
            currency: 'inr',
            description: 'Jewwllwry',
            source: (token),
          });
          console.log("charged",{charge})
          res.send("payment done")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("server is running on port" + PORT)
})
```

Comment: If you move the console.log(token_object.id); above fetch, do you see the correct value ?

Comment: Yes, the token is available at that position. I just checked it by moving it upwards.

Comment: Just edited my question but putting full NodeJS code.

Comment: ok, so if you send a get request to the node api does it work? or try a basic post which would return a string or something, its hard to say a solution to this but try step by step

Comment: I tried with get request and this one also fails.  What should i do now??

Comment: Open the browser in the simulator and check whether you can access the url,

Comment: I used ngrok and it solved my problem and I m able to charge the customer card however response received by react native side is a problem. If I used response.json() it throws an json parse error and if  I use response.text() the receive something like this ```["Success:","<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>\nThe server returned an invalid or incomplete response.\n</body></html>\n"]```. any thoughts on this?

Comment: Seems like something to do with network, better troubleshoot in that aspect

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your request with `http` instead of `https` as you you are working on local env.

Comment: yes, on local env. Tried with both https and http but to no avail

Comment: Ok so you are saying that you tried `http` in you `fetch` request and it also did'nt work.
As you are using `JSON.stringify()` in the body of your request. Try `source: JSON.parse(token)` in your api.

Comment: I am using IPv4 address from ipconfig command in place of IP. Does it has something to do with this??

Comment: Tried with ```JSON.parse(token)```, https,http. everytime getting network request fails

Comment: Remove the `response.json()` and just log the response there and see what it gives you there.